# how to match the single string and return whole string using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have code :
To search a single string and return whole string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function (){
var search = $('#input').val();
var str = $('#file').html();
var output=str.match(search );
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
  
  if (search.value.length > 0) {
  $(".oh").show().filter(function () {
    return $('#input').find('li').text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("search").val().toLowerCase()) == -1;
  }).hide();
}
else {
  $(".oh").show();
  document.getElementById( 'oh' ).style.display = 'block';
}
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="searchbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text"  id="input">
<button>solve</button>

<p id="result"></p>
<div id="file"class="oh"style="display:none;">
<li>beatiful</li>
<li>happy sunday</li><li>good morning</li><li>good evening</li><li>oh my god</li>I like u</li><li>wonderful day</li>

<li>good aftnoon</li>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For example:

```
`input = good
 output = good morning,
          good night,
          good noon`

`input = morning,
 output = good morning`
```

Its like a search box inside html
Please help me with any suggestion or correct my code its more helpful for me i have use jquery and index() are using but its not work

Comment: You have an invalid markup. that is why it is creating issues.

Comment: I am a new to html

Comment: posted an answer. see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this,  i have updated your markup little bit and changed the code to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var search = $('#input').val();  // get the search term
    var $lis = $('#file li'); // all the existing li items to filter/search
    var $resUl =  $('#result ul'); // the ul to show results

    var o = $lis.map(function() { // map will let you loop through list items
      if (this.textContent.indexOf(search) != -1) { // check if the current li in the iteration has the search term
        return $(this).clone(); // if yes then return a copy of it.
      }
    }).get(); // .get() will create an array when used with .map()
    $resUl.empty(); // always clear the result ul 
    $.each(o, function(i, item) { // loop through the array created via filter
      $resUl.append(item).find('li').fadeIn(); // here append them as lis are hidden so fade them in the view to show.
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#file li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button>solve</button>

<div id="result">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<ul id="file">
  <li>beatiful</li>
  <li>happy sunday</li>
  <li>good morning</li>
  <li>good evening</li>
  <li>oh my god</li>
  <li>I like u</li>
  <li>wonderful day</li>
  <li>good aftnoon</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if i type with `good` output only `good afternoon`but the input string match with three function `good afternoon,good morning,good evening`I would like to print all matched string with full line.

Comment: You are welcome and don't forget to mark this answer.

Comment: please explain the javascript

Comment: i'll put comments there.

Comment: @PrasanthKlr You can find the explanations in the comments.

Comment: i dont get any comment please add a comments

Comment: @PrasanthKlr comments are in the each line of js code above in the answer if you look up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function (){
        var searchval = $('#input').val();
        var str = $('#file').html();

        var rep2 = str.split('</li>');
        var rep3 = rep2.filter(function(item){
            if(item.search(searchval) !=-1){
                return item;
            }
        })
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = rep3;
    });
});
```